# Data not save in realtime database in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a user profile and connected with Firebase, but after save button the data is not shown in realtime database.

I have try many times and this is the realtime database rules, which are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

```
btnsaveprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        username = edtxtusername.getText().toString().trim();
        profession = spinnerprofession.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (username.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Your Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (profession.equals(getString(R.string.select_profession))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Your Profession", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            mprogressbarofsaveprofile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnsaveprofile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            String userId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
            User user = new User(username, profession);
            
            databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(user);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NexusHome.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

            btnsaveprofile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mprogressbarofsaveprofile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is User.class java code

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String profession;

    public User() {
    }
    public User(String username, String profession) {
        this.username = username;
        this.profession = profession;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
}
```

Please help me to correct this code and so can i save data in firebase.

Comment: Provide any error messages.

Comment: NOT SHOWING ANY ERROR WHEN I CLICK SAVE BUTTON THEN AUTOMATIC SHOW TOAST AND INTENT GOING TO NEXT ACTIVITY AFTER WHEN I SEE REALTIME DATABSE DO NOT SHOW ANY KIND OF DATA

Comment: I see. you dont have to write in capital letters!!

Comment: double check your document name id. check if the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The security rules you set on your database require that the user is signed in to Firebase Authentication. Yet in the code for your application, you don't check that - nor do you check whether the write operation succeeds.

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) { //  Check if the user is signed in
    String userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); //  Use the user's UID
    User user = new User(username, profession);
    
    databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() { //  Handle success
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { //  Handle failure
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                Log.e("Database", "Write failed", e);
            }
        });
    
    ...
}
else {
    Log.w("Database", "No user was signed in"); //  No user was signed in, write to logcat
}
```